# Call a js function after reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js following code. `createNote()` function is called when I click a "**Crate Note**" button on webpage

```
function createNote() {
   alert( 'page created' );        // for example note is created here
   window.location = document.URL; // refresh page to show new added note
   showEditNotePopup(); 
}

function showEditNotePopup() { 
  alert( 'show note edit page' );  // for example edit note popup shown here
}
```

Above code is working and creating note and also refreshing page using `window.location = document.URL;`. But after reloading page it is not calling `showEditNotePopup(`) function. Is there any way to achieve this without using AJAX.

Comment: for refreshing use just: location.reload()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens here, is that, you are sending a completely new **HTTP Request** to the server using `window.location`. Thus, it's not possible to do that. However, there are some workarounds. I'll write them here:

One way is to send another parameter to the server on `window.location`. For example:

```
window.location = document.URL + "?popup=true";
```

Now, on the server, check this parameter. If it exist, then create a **self-invoked** function to show the newly created note's info.

Another approach is to use ajax, instead of full request. This way, your function would be:

```
function createNote() {
   alert( 'page created' );        
   // use ajax to store new page, and update the UI accordingly
   showEditNotePopup(); 
}
```

Now, `showEditNotePopup();` works like a charm.